# what happens if I declare and initialize a static variable? Will its value be set on every call?

Tags: c

Let's say I have the following piece of code:

```
void foo(){
    static int bar = 0;
    bar++;
}
```

Does two successive calls to this function reset the value of the variable?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: The compiler could optimize that code to `void foo(void) { }` since the change in the value of `bar` is not observable outside `foo()`.  However, for the general case, where you changing `bar` has some observable effect — e.g. `int foo(void) { static in tbar = 0; return ++bar; }` — then, as noted in the accepted answer, `bar` is set to `0` when the program starts and not reset when the function is called.  If you wanted `bar` set to `0` on each call, you'd use an ordinary automatic local variable: `void foo(void) { int bar = 0; …code using bar…; }` or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialization occurs when an object is created. For static objects, their lifetimes start when program execution starts. They are not reinitialized or reassigned when execution reaches the statements that define them.